# How do I fix this code to allow it to compile?

Tags: hubot

I'm trying to program a script for hubot, and it seems I have an unclosed string.  The contents will appear in an html format with emoji like :smile: etc.  It isn't compiling in Cofeescript.  I'm new to javascript, any help would be appreciated.

The error I got is

```
 ERROR Unable to load /var/discourse/avebot/scripts/test: /var/discourse/avebot/scripts/test.js:5
    msg.reply("Hello! I’m Avebot, and I will be your guide throughout your training. :smile: <br>
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
  at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
```

and the script is:

```
robot.hear(/hi bot/, function(msg) {

    msg.reply("Hello! I’m a bot, and I will be your guide your training. :smile: <br>

<br>After finishing this training, you will be able to do x y z. :tada:<br>
Are you ready? If so, let me know you are ready by replying 'yes I’m ready!'");

    //Start a dialog with the user that sent this message.
    var dialog = switchBoard.startDialog(msg);

    //Provide choices for the next step, wait for the user.
    dialog.addChoice(/yes/, function(msg2){  msg2.reply('Okay');}

    dialog.addChoice( /no/, function(msg2){    msg2.reply("Okay, I'll wait"); }

    //The dialog will expire after 30 secods.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `'` in `I'm Avebot` by putting a backslash before the apostrophe (so it's `I\'m Avebot`).

Check out [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) site here for more information on JS escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

in order to define multiline strings in Javascript you can use backslash `\` before new lines

```js
msg.reply("Hello! I’m a bot, and I will be your guide your training. :smile: <br>\
<br>After finishing this training, you will be able to do x y z. :tada:<br>\
Are you ready? If so, let me know you are ready by replying 'yes I’m ready!'");
```